# SharePoint 2013 - content search webpart results - on hover

Tags: 2013, content-search-web-part

How can i disable the 'hover content' when the user mouses over a content search result (please see image attachment).

This is a content search query webpart pulling results from the blog/news

[image]

I cannot see this in the CSS or JS, please help is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Looks like a tooltip top me. Use F12 developer tool to check the description field and see if you can find anything.

Comment: Which OOTB template you are using ? It's the alt tag in HTML

Comment: This will be under title tag of the div. You can write a JS to remove title from search results or you can create a new display template. You can find complete steps here https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/sharepoint-design-manager-display-templates.

Comment: Thanks guys, will try and report back. Starting to think its trying to pick up some bootstrap js